# Is it dangerous to leave my car idling while I sleep in a garage?

Tags: project-zomboid

I've been playing around in Project Zomboid and I’m trying to survive during winter. I'd like to keep my survivor warm inside the car while they rest, as well as ensuring zombies have a harder time reaching my character.

I read somewhere that it's dangerous to run a portable generator indoors because the fumes emitted can hurt your character. Does a similar mechanic exist for sleeping in a confined space while I leave my car idling?

Comment: Don’t know about in the game but I would not recommend it in real life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this for a few reasons:

- You're worried about attracting zombies as a given and this noise will draw them in, even if you're inside a garage, they'll be knocking at the door, making more noise and you'll be surrounded.
- Secondly, what happens if you run out of fuel in the night, you'll just freeze to death.

But to answer your question, no it's not dangerous to leave it idling (from what I've read).

Comment: The engine idling is quieter than driving and it consumes significantly less gas in an idle state vs driving. You can easily make it through the night on anything more than a quarter tank of gas

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, for posterity's sake at least:

No. Currently, as of the date of this answer, there is no danger to your health from a running vehicle in a small, confined space.